# Woocommerce product filter meta key

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have built a search a form at custom page in wordpress and want to filter product on shop page using meta keys that are already exists into posts table.

Initially I have tried to filter categories at form page like this but it doesn't work.

```
$meta_query = array(
    'key'   => '_years', 
    'value' => '2009'
);
$args=array(
    'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'orderby'        => $orderby,
    'order'          => $order,
    'paged'          => $paged
);

wc_product_dropdown_categories($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

The meta_query parameter must be change in an array of array for a single custom field handling:

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
       'key'     => '_year',
       'value'   => '2009',
       'compare' => '>',
   )
);
```

Some details from [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) page in the Single Custom field handling part

Hope it will work with this.